# Keep users logged in even without “remember me” checked on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, cookies

Currently users are logged out right when their browsers close and/or if remember me isn't checked. Is there a way to keep users logged in even when their browsers close? I'd like to keep them logged in even if they haven't checked "Remember Me". The only time they should be logged out is if they log out themselves.

I know others have answered this question, but the difference with this question is Remember Me having to be checked. I'm being repetitive I apologize, but I'd like to keep them logged in even if Remember Me isn't checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set user auth cookies with wp_login action hook.
example :-

```
function zillion_set_auth_cookie( $user_login,  $user) {
    //do stuff
    if($user){
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID);
    }
    
}
add_action('wp_login', 'zillion_set_auth_cookie', 10, 2);
```

I hope it helps.